# Sort an ArrayList<Any> that contains two type of data classes

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, arraylist

so my problem is that I have an ArrayList that contains two types of data. The first one is the following class:

```
data class TextMessage (
    val content: String,
    val date: Date,
    val type: Int
)
```

The second class changes only the content type. So I'm creating a list that contains this two types of data and I want to sort it using the date value, that both of the types contains it, but I'm not finding any solution on internet that helps me, actually I don't know if it's possible to do that because I started to learn Kotlin a few days ago.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks, see ya.

Comment: please post your second class as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferably you want the two classes to share some super type. For example an interface. You could then have the common properties defined in the interface. Something like this:

```
interface Message {
    val date: Date
}

data class TextMessage (
    val content: String,
    override val date: Date,
    val type: Int
) : Message


data class OtherMessage (
    override val date: Date
) : Message
```

You could then sort a list of `Message` by doing this:

```
val sortedList = listOfMessages.sortedBy { it.date }
```

If you can't change your classes like this, you would have to rely on a check that might throw exceptions. Something like this:

```
val sortedList = listOfAny.sortedBy {
    when(it) {
        is TextMessage -> it.date
        is OtherMessage -> it.date
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type for sorting!")
    }
}
```